# How to get the latest records from databse using EF model and ICollectionView on datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am asking this question after a weeks trying and googling and I couldnt solve this.

In my application, I use EF model. I have a screen called TransportPlanning. In that I have  a datagrid which is bound to a ICollection as below:

```
 ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstOrdsRlsd);
```

where lstOrdsRlsd is an List of a table entity called OrdsRlsd as below:

```
List<OrdsRlsd> lstOrdsRlsd = new List<OrdsRlsd>();
```

I am using ICollectionView for filtering.

I use a timer to bring latest records from the database as below:

```
 void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        lstOrdsRlsd = dbContext.OrdsRlsds.Where(o => o.Location == MillName).ToList();
        view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstOrdsRlsd);
        dgRecords1.ItemsSource = view;
    }
```

But I am not getting the latest records from the database. I need the modified records from the databse.

I am not using MVVM model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you query `dbContext` you get entities from context's cache. To get fresh data from DB you must create new instance of context or call context's Refresh  method.